# Word for reenacting emergency situations for training, etc

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word (or a combination of words) that describes reenacting emergency situations, including painted wounds, etc. Basically a name for the whole concept of painting wounds, reenacting injury, etc.

This is something that is often done by emergency services for training their staff for emergency real life situations, for example by the German Red Cross. In German we have the standing term ["Notfalldarstellung"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notfalldarstellung) for this, however I could not find a good equivalent one in English.

An example sentence using the term would be:

> We are having a seminar on **term** on Friday to learn how to paint realistic looking wounds.

Is anyone able to help me out here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Notfalldarstellung** appears to translate 'emergency representation" in AmE. From your question it appears you are particularly interested in in the accurate portrayal of medical emergencies using medical renderings and make-up

Medical Training - **Mass Casualty Drill** aka MCD  [JC University](https://www.hercampus.com/school/jcu/medical-training-mass-casualty-drill)

> Approximately 30 students volunteered their morning to help make this
>   event successful. This year, the situation involved a
>   (gunman/shooter), who was portrayed to have open fire on individuals
>   who were in the ground floor of the library. **Special effects makeup
>   was used to make the injuries look as real as possible.** Many
>   injuries include gunshot wounds to the head, neck, legs and abdomen.
>   Each volunteer was given an index card with two sides of information.
>   One side included patient information to give the person an idea of
>   how to act; this side was not seen or known to the emergency.

Mass Casualty Drills and mock Mass Casualty Drill are common appellations in the U.S. to prepare for a [MASCAR](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Mascal). These are performed with or without 'emergency representation.  In some cases mock victims are just marked with a tag describing the injury.

**moulage**;  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/moulage)

> 4. The use of materials such as molded latex body parts or theatrical makeup to simulate injuries or diseases on a volunteer or dummy, as
>      for use in training emergency response teams

is taught by many schools in the U.S. [Medical Injury Simulation](http://www.moulagesciences.com/) My sense is that the german word is similar to moulage: the rendering of realism to medical injuries in trainings.

[image: leg wound- severe]

Comment: It might improve the usefulness of this answer if you wrote more contextual information.  It seems like you're suggesting the phrase "mass casualty drill."  In what ways is this similar or different from "Notfalldarstellung?" Is "mass casualty drill" a common term in English, or is it just a term used by one University to refer to their own practices?

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime aye!

Comment: Thanks a lot already for the answer! With the further explanation it seems to be quite what I was looking for :)

Comment: "Mass casualty drill" is commonly used nowadays, but "drill" meaning "practice" has a long history. Fire drill, for example, is practice evacuation of a building as though it were on fire. Fake injuries are used not only in mass casualty drills (mass casualties being those that exceed the local hospital capacity) but also in other kinds of emergency drills.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a former RN in WA state. We did a mass causality scenario in school. We commonly called our fake wounds by the term ***moulage***.

> (French: casting/moulding) is the art of applying mock injuries for the purpose of training emergency response teams and other medical and military personnel.

-[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moulage)

Comment: Hello, Jordan, and welcome to EL&U. I have reformatted your answer to clean up the punctuation and capitalization. Also, I provided a source (although not a great one).